# How do I unit test this function with inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I unit test this function with inputs? search_by_choice is a variable that takes in user's input, but how do I unit test this?

```py
def search(books_data):
    """
    Searches and print search result as numbered list.

    A function that takes in menu_selection (an integer) as user input from menu(), run search_function() and collects
    the result from search_function(). Print user the result and return to main menu page, ie. menu().

    :precondition: the integer must be in the range [1:8]
    :postcondition: print number of results and numbered list of results as dictionaries
    :return: menu()
    """
    print(SEARCH_OPTIONS())
    search_by_choice = int(input("Please enter your choice (in number): ").strip())
    if search_by_choice == 1:
        print("You chose search by: Author")
        return 1
    elif search_by_choice == 2:
        print("You chose search by: Title")
        return 2
    elif search_by_choice == 3:
        print("You chose search by: Publisher")
        return 3
    elif search_by_choice == 4:
        print("You chose search by: Shelf")
        return 4
    elif search_by_choice == 5:
        print("You chose search by: Category")
        return 5
    elif search_by_choice == 6:
        print("You chose search by: Subject")
        return 6
    elif search_by_choice == 7:
        print("You chose to Return to previous page (Main Menu)")
        menu(load_data())
        # return 7
    elif search_by_choice == 8:
        print("You chose to Quit")
        quit_books(books_data)
    else:
        print("Error! Please enter a valid integer")
        menu(load_data())
```

Comment: This looks like the main part of your program, which uses all other parts - so it's not really a "unit" in the sense of unit testing. It is possible to redesign it to be more easily testable, otherwise manual testing is easier, or you can reroute stdin/stdout for the purpose of automated testing but the tests you write will likely be fragile.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
def numbers_to_strings(argument): 
     switcher = { 
        0: "zero", 
        1: "You chose search by: Author", 
        2: "You chose search by: Title", 
        3:
        .
        .
    } 
    # get() method of dictionary data type returns  
    # value of passed argument if it is present  
    # in dictionary otherwise second argument will 
    # be assigned as default value of passed argument 
    return switcher.get(argument, "nothing") 


# Driver program 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    argument=0
    print numbers_to_strings(argument)
```